# Really basic question on navigation

Tags: navigation

Why can't I navigate to /homeassistant?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
Bookshelf  Downloads      homeAssProd  Public            Templates
Desktop    get-docker.sh  Music        Python-3.8.0      Videos
Documents  homeassistant  Pictures     Python-3.8.0.tgz
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /homeassistant/
-bash: cd: /homeassistant/: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do `cd homeassistant`, because it is located in the directory you are in. `/homeassistant` refers to a folder in the root folder of your raspberry pi.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Yes.. doh!  Sorry sometimes I really need to engage brain.